# Azure Resource Manager - Updating Tags

Tags: rest, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'd like to be able to update tags of some specific resources (like VM, sql servers etc.) in my azure subscription using REST API. When I look at the API, I see that in order to do it I need to call the Update operation of the resource. Is there another, generic way (using REST API) which allows to update tags of any resource ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there is a generic way (using REST API) which allows to update tags of any Azure resource, including the tags for the resource group.

Each tag created under the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is actually created at the **subscription level**.

Hence, if you update a tag, it will actually update for all the resources and resource groups which have that tag under the same subscription.

The latest REST APIs (Api Version: **2016-09-01**) for create or update the tag can be found at the link below:

[Azure Resources Tags REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags)

Hope this helps!

Comment: so you mean, if i create a tag on vm, it is created on the subscription level?  how can i verify this. with Powershell\CLI or python SDK?

Comment: yes, easiest way to verify is in the Azure portal. When you create a new tag, you can reuse the tag for any resource at the same subscription level.

Comment: so what do you mean, I can't create 2 different tags with the same name? nah, that's not true

Comment: I mean, same tag with different value, how can you update that globally? I bet he's talking about values, not tag names.

Comment: I'd say both. My scenario is that a user can change value, delete a tag or create a new one.